# Euler #18 with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve [project euler problem 18](http://projecteuler.net/problem=18).
http://projecteuler.net/problem=18
I tried a greedy algorithm with python working from the bottom of the triangle.
THen I move up one row and find the biggest route with a greedy algorithm and try to connect the biggest route but it doesn't work. DO you have any hints that would put me on the right track without giving the solution of the problem away.

here is the function:

```
def greedy(i):
    if i%15==0:
        a=[(b[i-15],i-15),(b[i-14],i-14)]
        a=sorted(a)
        a=a[-1]
    else:
        a=[(b[i-15],i-15),(b[i-16],i-16),(b[i-14],i-14)]
        a=sorted(a)
        a=a[-1]
    return a
```

Cheers

Comment: @Juhana I believe he's referring to this : http://projecteuler.net/problem=18

Comment: Hint: This is not a greedy problem.

Comment: a wild answer appears: http://snipplr.com/view/35587/project-euler--problem-18/ ... search engines are your friend ...

Comment: the best method is to just do the sum, you dont need the route just the max sum, so for the every value in a row (starting from second) sum the max value between  the value above and in the left and the value just above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you ever heard of [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)?

Consider this problem. What makes a route the best? Is there any relation between the last step and the previous ones? Also, look at this triangle where the greedy algorithm doesn't give you the right answer:

```
      1
    2   3
  9   1   2
1   1   2   4
```

Comment: I think the best method is to work backwards for this problem, not sure what you mean by dynamic programming for this.

Comment: @jamylak: You can go top-down or bottom-up with memoization. Both are the same.

Comment: Yes that was what i was referring to.

Comment: Thank you Ziyao Wei
I had a look at the wikipedia article, I found it very complicated. I do programming as a hobby.
The triangle in your example can be solved very easily with a greedy algorithm starting from the bottom. Obviously this approach doesn't work with euler problem 18.

Comment: @user1119429: You don't have to read that, just think hard should be enough:) Hint: If there is a optimal path from top to the bottom, then for the subpath without the last number, it must have which property? (bottom-up is just the same). Also, I edited the example, now greedy won't work.

Comment: Thank you Ziyao. I haven't figured it out yet but I am going to think hard.